# qt QUrl Opening a pdf

Tags: qt, pdf, qurl

I am trying to open a pdf file with the default application through Qt's "DesktopServices" class.

But I am coming up with a ShellExecute

```
'file:///C:/PMPS/PMPSv1/Instuctionsforuse.pdf' failed (error 2). problem.
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <QDesktopServices>
#include <QUrl>

}

void Dialog::guideButtonClicked()
{
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///C:/PMPS/PMPSv1/Instuctionsforuse.pdf"));
}
```

Comment: try with: `QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl:::fromLocalFile("C:/PMPS/PMPSv1/Instuctionsforuse.pdf"));`

Comment: Still get the same error: ShellExecute 'file:///C:/PMPS/PMPS??v1/Instuctionsforuse??.pdf' failed (error 2).

Comment: Try with `QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl:::fromLocalFile("C://PMPS//PMPS‌v1//Instuctionsforuse‌​.pdf"));`

Comment: Or `QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl:::fromLocalFile("C:\\PMPS\\PM‌​PS‌v1\\Instuctionsfo‌​ruse‌​.pdf"));`

Comment: Still same error...

Comment: A very simple option to know the path is that you right click on the .pdf and you will have it with your browser and show the URL.

Comment: Path is correct...

Comment: I refer to the format of the path, in windows it is always a problem.

Comment: QUrl localfile = QUrl::fromUserInput("file:///C:/PMPS/PMPSv1/Instuctionsforuse.pdf"); You can check if it is correct with qDebug() << localfile.toLocalFile();

Comment: Ah yep that's fixed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already has handlers in your Url (like `file://` etc), or if your Url is already encoded and should be used without any conversion and changes, use [QUrl::fromUserInput](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#fromUserInput) function. When the string is not already a valid URL, a best guess is performed, making various web related assumptions.

```
QUrl localfile = QUrl::fromUserInput("file:///C:/PMPS/PMPSv1/Instuctionsforus‌​e.pdf");
```

You can check if it is correct with:

```
 qDebug() << localfile.toLocalFile();
```